# Individual point coloring in ListPlot, ErrorListPlot in Mathematica

Tags: colors, wolfram-mathematica, plot, points

I can get a colored `ListLinePlot` by doing something like

```
ListLinePlot[Range[420, 680, 20], ColorFunction -> "VisibleSpectrum", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, as indicated by the help file ("`ColorFunction` requires at least one dataset to be `Joined`"), if I do the equivalent

```
ListPlot[Range[420, 680, 20], ColorFunction -> "VisibleSpectrum", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

all my points are blue.  Is there a nice way to get `ColorFunction` to work for `ListPlot` with `Joined -> False`?

That is, is there a nicer way to get something like

```
ListPlot[
 List /@ Transpose[{Range[(680 - 420)/20 + 1], Range[420, 680, 20]}], 
 PlotMarkers -> ({Graphics[{#, Disk[]}], 0.05} & /@ ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"] /@ Range[420, 680, 20])
]
```

?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Also, does anyone have an explanation of *why* Mathematica requires `Joined -> True` in order to make use of `ColorFunction`?)

Edit: I'm also looking for a way to do a similar coloring with `ErrorListPlot` in the `ErrorBarPlots` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that Joined->True draws a Line[] which can be given VertexColors for each containing point. I assume doing the same for the points when setting Joined->False leads to situations where it does not work. Nevertheless, Line[] and Point[] work pretty much the same in your case. So what is about

```
ListLinePlot[Range[420, 680, 20], ColorFunction -> "VisibleSpectrum", 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False] /. Line[arg___] :> Point[arg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And, by the way, if your using a ListLinePlot only, where the only Line[] directives arising are the one from your data, this should work even if you have more datasets and {x,y} coordinates

```
data = Transpose[Table[{{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}]];
ListLinePlot[data, ColorFunction -> Hue] /. Line[arg___] :> Point[arg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a similarly nice solution for `ErrorListPlot` in the `ErrorBarPlots` package?

Comment: And you can add something like `PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5]` in the code -- i.e. the code that draws the lines -- to control the eventual point size.

Comment: @Jason, an `ErrorListPlot` can not be colorized with a short trick like the above for at least two reasons: The objects which should have the same color are split up into several Graphics-directives. You would have to find corresponding lines and points. The second reason is, that *one* point has *one* position which is used for the color. An `ErrorBar` has several different positions. So it's not clear which one you like to use for the color. Check the `InputForm` of your `ErrorListPlot`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DiscretePlot`:

```
data = Range[420, 680, 20];
DiscretePlot[data[[i]], {i, Length[data]},
   ColorFunction -> "VisibleSpectrum", ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   Filling -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you're plotting a list of x,y points, it gets a little trickier:

```
data = Transpose[{Range[420, 680, 20], Range[400, 530, 10]}];
mapping = Apply[Rule, data, 2];
DiscretePlot[i/.mapping, {i, data[[;;,1]]},
   ColorFunction -> "VisibleSpectrum", ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   Filling -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It does seem rather odd that `DiscretePlot` will let you color the points differently whereas `ListPlot` won't. I'm sure it must have something to do with the implementation details, but I can't think of a reason why that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem in my work too. I assign a colour to each point in the following manner:

```
data = ...
ListPlot[data] /. Point[args___] :> Point[args, VertexColors -> {c1, c2, ...}]
```

where `c1` is the colour for the first data point, and so on. The colour list may be programmatically generated, eg

```
ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ (Range@Length@data / Length@data)
```

[Here is the result.](http://xxx.fivefourseven.com/stack-4.png)

The good points of this method are as follows.

- It's straightforward: we have a list of pairs, then we create a corresponding list of colours.
- Our original `ListPlot` code needs not be modified (eg, changed into `ListLinePlot`).